# pass data with SimpleHttpOperator to trigger cloud function 2nd gen

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-composer

I have the following task:

```
this_is_a_task = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id= 'task_id',
    method='POST',
    http_conn_id='conn_id',
    endpoint='/?test=foo',
    # data={"test": "foo"},
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

on the cloud functions side, I'm trying to catch the parameters with the two following ways:

```
# catching data
# test_data = request.get_json().get('test')
# print('test: {}'.format(test))

# catching end point
test_endpoint = request.args.get('test')
print('test: {}'.format(test))
```

the second option is working (`request.args.get('test')`) however when trying the first option `request.get_json().get('test')` I'm getting a 400 request error.

so if I'm not using the `endpoint` variable from my `SimpleHttpOperator` how can I catch the json object pass into the `data` variable?

Comment: Can you try this `test_data = request.get_json().get('data')`?

Comment: I tried it already indeed and same result!

Comment: Can you share the detailed error/logs you encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your issue and based on this [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/operators.html#:%7E:text=In%20the%20first%20example%20we%20are%20calling%20a%20POST%20with%20json%20data%20and%20succeed%20when%20we%20get%20the%20same%20json%20data%20back%20otherwise%20the%20task%20will%20fail.) you need to add `json.dumps` when you are calling a `POST` with json data. Then provide [authentication credentials](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_developer_testing) as a Google-generated ID token stored in an Authorization header.

See below sample code:

```
import datetime
import json

from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import bash
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

with models.DAG(
        'composer_quickstart',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    # Print the dag_run id from the Airflow logs
    gen_auth = bash.BashOperator(
        task_id='gen_auth', bash_command='gcloud auth print-identity-token '
    )

    auth_token = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='gen_auth') }}"
    
    this_is_a_task = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='task_id',
        method='POST',
        http_conn_id='cf_conn1',
        data=json.dumps({"test": "foo"}),
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json","Authorization": "Bearer " + auth_token}
    )
    
    gen_auth >> this_is_a_task
```

[image]

On the cloud functions side tried to use below sample code:

```
test_data = request.get_json().get('test')
print(test_data)
    
return test_data
```

You can also test your function using this curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"test": "foo"}' "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" https://function-5-k6ssrsqwma-uc.a.run.app
```

[image]

Comment: I've allowed `Allow unauthenticated` request on my function... do I still need to handle authorization?

Comment: ok so I just forgot the `json.dumps()` which is, as you mentioned, indicated in the documentation. sorry :/